# Restoring a Postgresql dump file

Tags: postgresql, restore, dump

I need to restore a Postgresql dump file to get some data out of it (note never used Postgresql before)

I've tried using the command line using the following (with relevant details filled in)

```
psql -U {user-name} -d {desintation_db}-f {dumpfilename.sql}
```

And initially it looks like it's working, lot's of drops and alters flashing up. But then it ends and nothing's in the db. Looking through the dump file it doesn't look like it actually got to the end either.

I've also tried just opening the dump file in a SQL Editor and executing it on my db, but a short way into the file it errors with "syntax error at or near "1" on this line

```
--
-- Data for Name: admin_groups; Type: TABLE DATA; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

COPY admin_groups (ref, title, is_locked, created, updated) FROM stdin;
1   Default t   2011-05-25 15:13:46.474025  2011-05-25 15:13:46.474025
2   Root    t   2011-05-25 15:13:54.137801  2011-05-25 15:13:54.137801
\.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: probably you lost EOL (new lines symbols) from dump - any data row should be on separate line.

Answer (score 3):

This eventually worked for me

```
psql -f {dump file name} {db name}
```

Answer (score 2):

For restore database dump file in Postgresql use this sql command

```
pg_restore -p 5433 -U postgres -d databasename  -v "/var/tmp/dumpfilename.dump"
```

For dump data base in Postgresql use this SQL command

```
pg_dump -p 5433 -U postgres -F c -b -v -f "/var/tmp/dumpfilename.dump" databasename
```

Here port number(5433) based on installation which port number we given that port number we use.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
This answer helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15155659/18361507 
When installing using the **default path** on **Windows**:

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\bin>psql -U {username} -f {path to .dump} {db name}
```